# How can I pick one of a set of overloaded functions in Scala

Tags: scala, overloading

How can I refer to one overload of a function?  Does this require reflection?

```
----- Define two functions with the same signature

scala> def f( x:Int ) = x + 1
f: (x: Int)Int

scala> def g( x:Int ) = x + 2
g: (x: Int)Int

----- Define a function that returns one or the other

scala> def pick( a:Boolean ) = if (a) f _ else g _
pick: (a: Boolean)Int => Int

scala> pick(true)(0)
res24: Int = 1

scala> pick(false)(0)
res25: Int = 2

----- All good so far; now overload f to also take a String

scala> def f( x:String ) = x.toInt + 1
f: (x: String)Int

scala> def pick( a:Boolean ) = if (a) f _ else g _
pick: (a: Boolean)String with Int => Int

scala> pick(false)(0)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: String with Int
              pick(false)(0)
                          ^
```

I understand why this doesn't work.  But how can I define pick to use the f that takes an Int, and ignore the f that takes a String?

Again, I don't want to write a function that calls either f or g.  I want to write a function that *returns* f or g, which I can then call gazillions of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a type annotation:

```
def pick( a:Boolean ) = if (a) f(_: Int) else g(_: Int)
```

Comment: Awesome -- thanks.  Note to others reading this that in order to see this work in the REPL you have to use paste mode (as som-snytt demonstrates).

Answer (score 1):

Supplement: Don't be fooled by how the REPL constructs what it runs:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Foo {
def f(i: Int) = i.toString
def f(s: String) = s
def pick( a:Boolean ) = if (a) f _ else "nope"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:10: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method f in object Foo of type (s: String)String
and  method f in object Foo of type (i: Int)String
match expected type ?
       def pick( a:Boolean ) = if (a) f _ else "nope"
                                      ^
```

Using the REPL, the other answer to your question is, define the one you want last, because it becomes most specific:

```
scala> def f(s: String) = s
f: (s: String)String

scala> def f(i: Int) = i.toString
f: (i: Int)String

scala> f _
res0: Int => String = <function1>
```

Comment: Good to know!  Unfortunately in my case the methods in question are part of the Spray folks' routing DSL, so I can't control their order...